# Point IntelliJ to installed Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, plugins

I'm new to **Scala** and **IntelliJ**.

I have already installed Scala on my Ubuntu PC:

```
printdoc@print$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_181).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Then, I install **IntelliJ**. I know that we need install **Scala plugin** to use Scala with **IntelliJ**. But I wonder if it will be duplicated because I already have Scala in my computer?

If so, how can I point the **Scala location** for **IntelliJ**, so that the IDE can re-use scala, instead of download a new one.
Which is a better practice, between installing Scala plugin and reusing installed Scala?

The same question for **sbt** with **IntelliJ**.

Comment: "Installing" Scala or SBT through IntelliJ is basically you telling IntelliJ how to interpret Scala and run code within the IDE. I don't know if it actually re-installs Scala or SBT or anything, but even if it does it won't be a drain on your computer. At the very least, it shouldn't break anything -  I have always installed Scala and SBT both through Terminal and IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not using sbt with IntelliJ, you *can* manually choose to use the Scala jars installed on your system, but I recommend letting IntelliJ handle it. That makes it easier to select or upgrade the Scala SDK used with your project. The files may be duplicated, but that is an insignificant amount of storage.

But to answer your question, to use an installed Scala library:

1. open Project structure menu / Project Settings / Modules
2. click the `+`
3. select `Library...`

[image]

4. select `New Library` / `Scala SDK`

[image]

5. To use a specific version, select it if available, or choose `Download`. **OR** click `Browse` and navigate to your scala installation and choose the relevant jars.

[image]